# How can I create a Job or event in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a job in `mysql` which runs on the end of the day, where in that job I would like to update some of the column values in my tables. Assume I am having 2 tables where I am having a column named `Status` which is either `Pending or Accepted`. For this I would like to create a Job where I would like to search the two tables and set `Pending` status to `Accepted`.

Is it possible to have

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use MySQL's [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE EVENT foo ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY STARTS '2012-10-05 00:00:00' DO BEGIN
  UPDATE table1 SET Status = 'Accepted' WHERE Status = 'Pending';
  UPDATE table2 SET Status = 'Accepted' WHERE Status = 'Pending';
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```