# MySQL Trigger on Table A, INSERT OR UPDATE table B with TIMESTAMPDIFF()

Tags: mysql, triggers, heidisql

I have 2 tables - clients and client_history.

```
CLIENTS:
    cID | last_seen  (LAST_SEEN is updated every 2 mins by my application)

CLIENT_HISTORY :
    ID | cID | left_left | time_arrived
```

I'm trying to:

Record the comings and goings of clients over time. So when clients.last_seen is older than 5 minutes, INSERT record into client_history with the cID, and the clients.last_seen values.

I want something like:

```
 BEGIN
  IF (-- something here is true)
  THEN
    INSERT INTO client_history
    SET
      cID=old.cID,
      last_seen=old.last_seen;
  ELSEIF (-- something here is true)
  THEN
    INSERT INTO client_history
    SET
      time_arrived=old.last_seen
  END IF;
END
```

I've been looking at using

```
IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,c.last_seen,NOW()) > 5) for the first IF condition.
```

I'm new to triggers, and I don't know if my logic is good, or if there's a simpler or better way to do this. I was wondering if I could introduce a flag column to indicate a client left or something like that.

Comment: When you are not using `new` and `old` data; it does not make any sense to use trigger

Comment: Are you saying I should amend my SQL?

Comment: I would recommend you to google some good tutorial on Trigger. It will explain the meaning of `NEW` and `OLD` keywords in context of the trigger. If you are not using those; it does not make any sense to use Triggers for your activity

Comment: Thanks, I've googled a lot of stuff on this, and can't find a solution which is why I'm posting here. I've added to the OP with something I tried using OLD keyword.

Comment: If I understand your problem right trigger is not the right solution for you. You want to update the client_history table given a period of time not changes in the date itself. The right solution for this kind of situation would be to use MySQL events: here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726805/460557 and the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: I want to update the client_history table when the application updates the clients table. So when clients.last_seen is updated, but with a value more than 5 minutes older than current time, then INSERT is made into client_history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get it for you.

```
DELIMETER $$
CREATE TRIGGER monitor
AFTER UPDATE
ON clients
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, OLD.last_seen, NEW.last_seen ) > 5)
THEN INSERT INTO client_history (cID, left_left)-- or whichever column here
SELECT NEW.cID, NEW.last_seen FROM client_history;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMETER ;
```

I thought to use the `NEW.last_seen` value in the logic instead of `NOW()` function.

Comment: I also wasn't sure if during the UPDATE, if the cID value is changed too.

Comment: Thanks very much - great idea! This has done exactly what I needed, and I've added your blog to my weekly reading-with-coffee list :)

Comment: @JamesPy. Awesome to know it worked for you! Also many many thanks for following my blog .